Why doesn't [^\\.\\s]+ regular expression work?
This result of this code should be false. Why doesn't [^\.\s]+ work? I want to find if string has no dots or spaces for a string that's longer than one character.
 import java.util.regex.*;
    public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("[^\\.\\s]+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("d ");
            System.out.println(matcher.find());
        }
    }


You should edit your question to explain what you are trying to do. The reason that your current regex matches is that d matches the regex.

I figured out the solution myself. The solution is ((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\.\s]+) which  is better for performance than matching the whole string because I'm trying to detect a variable declaration or assignment. To detect a variable declaration or assignment is ^(\s+((?:[a-zA-Z])[^.\s]+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z])[^.\s]+)+(?=\s*=|;))

A variable declaration and an assignment are two entirely different things. Besides that, where do these rules come from? Your “solution” requires names to have at least two characters, restricting the first to be an ASCII letter while the second can be anything, e.g. a= is a valid identifier according to your “solution”. Is this supposed to match a real programming language?

I want two characters because one character would change all characters for one speciific character in a JTextArea. I'm using that regex to change a variable throughout all code.

I figured it out, the answer was ((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\.\s]+)
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Main {
    protected JTextArea textarea;
    public static void main(String[] args) {                    
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\\.\\s]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(" b");
        return matcher.find();
    }
}

To detect variable declaration:
^(\s+((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\.\s]+)\s+((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\.\s]+)+(?=\s*=|;))
Matching a whole string is slower than finding a part of string.

Incidentally, you don't need to escape the . -- it has no special meaning inside a character class.

why are you using (?: ? Why the capturing group (...)? "Matching a whole string" is something different than "finding a part of a string", it does not matter which is faster, it matters what you need to do - match the whole or find a part (none is explained in the question)

The original question was asking for "d " input to work. "d " input doesn't work without (?: regex. I wanted to know both ways for a whole or part of a string.

There is an infinite number of regex producing false for your input string. You have to explain why this particular one is a solution to your problem. It might help if you include a description of your actual problem in your question. You should also explain why your solution required changing the input string, adding an unused JTextArea field, and introducing compiler errors.

I wrote "I want to find if string has no dots or spaces for a string that's longer than one character." in the question!

And how does a pattern like [a-zA-Z] which only matches an ASCII letter match the problem description of checking that a string “has no dots or spaces”? Besides that, your actual intention is hinted at in this comment, so it’s a typical xy problem. Letting aside that this answer does not even match your literal question, it is far away from identifying declarations of a programming language

The question content had the words "that's longer than one character." When I was referring to character, I was referring to only the English alphabet. Often people say character when they are generally referring to the English alphabet.

You might want to use matches() instead of find().
The find() method returns true if the input sequence's subsequence matches the pattern. So "d" matches with the pattern => return true
The matches() method attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
System.out.println(matcher.matches());


Matching the whole string is slowing than detecting first half of string. I found the solution, the solution is ((?:[a-zA-Z])[^\.\s]+)
